# intercepting chrome.exe causes chrome not to work

Tags: google-chrome

I have numerous programs that launch the current web browser on constructed HTML files, and it needs to open in a new window. Many places in the registry reference chrome.exe. There are so many it's hit or miss editing each to have "--new-window". I renamed chrome.exe to chrome_original.exe and replaced chrome.exe with a program I made. What my program does is pass command line arguments to chrome_original.exe, adding "--new-window" if not already present. A config file is read for options. For instance I can keep a log of invocations. There are times when adding "--new-window" is not appropriate, which can be determined by examining the log.

On my development machine the strategy works excellent, but on other machines it doesn't. On the other machines chrome loads, but just sits there with the wheel spinning. Does it test to see if the exe being run is chrome.exe? Why does it work on my development machine?

If chrome updates itself with a new version, putting things back like they were, when I redeploy my exe it will take care of that.

I need to get this working if anyone has an idea why chrome will just sit with the wheel spinning and not load a page. Thanks

Comment: please delete this comment, done by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. Chrome also runs as a background process, sitting in the tray, utilizing the same exe. When loaded, the exe file is not held open. Having the exe already loaded as one file name, then loading again as a different file name, no doubt causes confusion. What was already loaded needed to be unloaded, first. In addition, the auto start registry key value needed to be updated with the new exe file name.

I have yet to see what will happen when chrome updates itself automatically with a new version. There's a good chance the launching utility will be overwritten. Some tweaking will need to be done.

Using a launcher for chrome to intercept invocations works really well and is a good approach to always having a new window when one is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the problem I recommend that you install Process Explorer from www.sysinternals.com.

There should be no Chrome "sitting around with the wheel spinning".
In Process Explorer find out which is the process, double click it and in the first tab in the window that opens you see the command line.

Compare it with the command line on the computer where it works.

Process Explorer gives you much more information, like for example the environment variables. I saw in the case of Firefox that Environment variables may be very relevant. For example when you start Firefox by your program and do not set the working directory correctly it may hang.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not going to bring process explorer into this. The issue is chrome.exe. If I rename chrome.exe to chrome_original.exe, then double click the file, pages do not load. The little pinwheel spins indefinitely. If I rename back to chrome.exe and double click the file, pages then load. For pages to load the name of the file must be chrome.exe. But on my development machine this is not the case. Pages load with whatever name the executable has. There should be no difference with my development machine and any other machine in this regard

Comment: Something is different between your machines. But you are not interested in finding out what it is. If you prefer your theory over facts, you are right: You should not investigate more! But why do you ask all here?

Comment: I have used process explorer and am familiar with it. It is often a good entry point when solving a problem. If renaming chrome.exe to something else causes it not to work, then putting it back allows it to work again, the problem is most likely configuration. What I'm hoping is for someone to read this who is already familiar with the specific issue. Process explorer is not needed to trace anything since we already know renaming the exe file and running it causes chrome to quit working properly. What I've done here is document what was seen in the hope someone can make something of it.